# How to ban a specific country from using my app programmatically - android java

Tags: java, android

so let's say that i want to ban the country X from using my app, i banned it from the google play store but it can still be downloaded via VPN is there a way to ban this country using code (maybe trying to detect the user's location or something?)

my government has a very big problem with a neighboring country and i'll go to jail for like forever if i had users in it.

Comment: Never guess the requirements. This is a case where you need official answer. Do they provide communication or ways to check that said user belongs to country? If no, then wait until they do

Answer (score 1):

> my government has a very big problem with a neighboring country and i'll go to jail for like forever if i had users in it.

There is no technological way that you can guarantee that your mobile application can't / won't be used by someone in another country.  Anything that you do in your application can be defeated by a user with sufficient ingenuity / time.

You need to talk to a good local lawyer to find out *precisely* what your country's law means, and what you need to do to comply with it<sup>1</sup>.  But if the law requires you to do things that are technically impossible, your safest bet may be to not write / publish any mobile apps.  Seriously.

---

<sup>1 - It is unlikely that anyone here really knows.  I certainly don't!</sup>

Answer (score -1):

`Locale.getDefault()`

Gives you the locale information about the phone, this information come from settings and can be changed by user

but if you want ensure the user from specific country doesn't use you app just get the GPS position and in case of be that country close it

Comment: i was searching around and, i didn't find any way to get the user's country. (i found some ways that does it by detecting the language of the device but that's not practical)

Comment: is an app? for smartphone? smartphones have gps use it

Comment: oh i am not trying to make my app look like a big thing, i am just trying comply with the law

Comment: The GPS location for a device can be faked.  https://www.xda-developers.com/fake-android-location/

Comment: this is easily detectable, to mock gps position user need to hava developper mode on, the app can check if its on and stop running

Comment: On a rooted device, I expect that there are more subtle (maybe undetectable) ways to spoof the GPS location.  Then there are people who like to turn off GPS.

Comment: the root status of a phone is also detectable... all what you are saying are easy variables to check... if they all are "ok" according to his rules, the software open, otherwise it closes... but any further discursion is pointless as the whole app idea also have been discouraged

Comment: *this information come from settings and can be changed by user* - in other words, it is useless. Why even suggest it

Comment: The root status can be faked.  If you have root, you can fake anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform multiple checks like does a user's IP match banned country IPs, you can check mobile carrier, you can eventually make location check which of course will require user's permission.